# Unity advertisement package breaks android build?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gradle

My project seemed to be working just fine, until I installed unity's advertisement package. With it, I have gradle errors thrown every time I try to build for android, and the build fails after 10 minutes.

I've tried re-installing unity, installing a new version, installing an older version(2021 LTS is my current one), commenting android.enableR8 inside the projecttemplate gradle file, changing gradle version to 3.4.0, forcing resolve, etc

Removing the package allows it to build without issues.

[image]

Comment: The editor log will have more information about exactly what failed. Open it up and search for `stderr`.

Comment: Looking through it, it seems theres MULTIPLE duplicated classes... any ways to auto fix that?

Comment: Depends on why it is happening. Make sure Jetifier is turned on in the resolver and run it. If that doesn't fix it you'll have to look at what each conflict is. You may have duplicate plugins or libraries in your plugins directory.

Comment: jetifier is on, I ran it, tried everything. Theres still duplicate classes

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning. Unfortunately, Unity reports it marked as an error. However, the error is the subsequent message. So, the specific reason in your case is logged under

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

It may thus very well be that you need to regenerate the file where the reported issue is in. E.g. *C:\Users\LOCALUSER.android\debug.keystore*. Simply, close your Unity project, remove the file (do a backup just in case), and restart Unity. However, to be certain, you should report the error.